# AJAX page load for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Recently, I came across this [**website**](http://weareroyale.com/#/work/featured). There, when you click on a portfolio item, you see is a loading text which has covered the item you clicked and the page loads below the header. It doesn't even leave the page to go to the other page.

How can this be achieved. My WordPress site [**here**](http://visualgarage.wearenakshatra.com/work/featured/), I've the look but only the ajax is left. Please help me out if you can, I really have no idea where to go from here :(

I've used the same image from this [**website**](http://weareroyale.com/#/work/featured). Just for working, will upload mine once done.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read how to ask a question correctly if you want people to help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using Advanced ajax page loader plugin and read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/) article as well. But stuck on how to implement it in WordPress.

Comment: It's expected that you have a specific development problem that you need help with. Unfortunately as it stands, this question is very broad and it's near-impossible to help you.

Answer (score 3):

There are various plugins available on WordPress plugins repository which will ajaxify your website.

- [Advanced AJAX Page Loader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/)
- [Ajaxify WordPress Site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/)

Only thing you need to do is configure the plugin setting properly by specifying the `ID` of main page content and rest will be taken care by plugin itself.

There is also a jquery plugin available i.e [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) which you can use and implement as per your requirements.

Hope it helps you.